# Maximizing console window - C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console, console-application

I'm working on a console application on C# and I need to open the console maximized. When I just hit the maximize button on the console window, it maximizes only on height and not in width. I tried to use the following code :

```
   Console.WindowWidth = 150;
   Console.WindowHeight = 61;
```

Which works almost as I want on my computer but gives error on some other computers.
What should I do to maximize the console?

Comment: _What error do you get_? Did you read it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683193(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: read this and look to SLaks comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670633/maximum-columns-for-a-console-in-c-sharp

Comment: @SLaks I don't have the exact error right here but it was something about the dimensions of the screens being smaller or larger then the current format or something like that.

Comment: @BassamAlugili thanks for the link, but this is only for dimensions and not maximizing it (like clicking on the maximize button on the right top).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Can't with the CLR.  Need to import Win32 API calls and poke your container window.  The following might help.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(System.IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);

private static void Maximize()
{
    Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 3); //SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
}
```

Answer (score 19):

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]

    private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
    private static IntPtr ThisConsole = GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    private const int HIDE = 0;
    private const int MAXIMIZE = 3;
    private const int MINIMIZE = 6;
    private const int RESTORE = 9;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       ShowWindow(ThisConsole, MINIMIZE);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation why does code solve the issue. Code only answers are discouraged.

Comment: This answer works even when you start your console application without debugger, the accepted answer doesnt. Another options is `FindWindowByCaption` in user32.dll

Comment: I suppose it should be `ShowWindow(ThisConsole, MAXIMIZE);`

Answer (score 1):

This works for a .NET 6 Console application:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]

static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
IntPtr ThisConsole = GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
const int HIDE = 0;
const int MAXIMIZE = 3;
const int MINIMIZE = 6;
const int RESTORE = 9;

ShowWindow(ThisConsole, MAXIMIZE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.SetWindowSize(Console.LargestWindowWidth, Console.LargestWindowHeight)
```