# How to fullscreen console

Tags: c#, .net

I want to **fullscreen** console as if you would press **Alt+Enter**. The only thing **somewhat** close to what I want is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053112/5659664), except it maximizes it, not fullscreen.

How would the code for that look?

Comment: One of the the answers in the question you linked allows you to maximize the console. Isn't that what you are asking for? If not, why not?

Comment: As said, I want to FULLSCREEN it, not MAXIMIZE it.

Comment: Fullscreen = no borders, no nothing, only the console. Maximized = borders, everything else, toolbar present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a console application and use this code:
[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0b374f73-5604-48ee-a720-53bb5b19467b/maximizing-the-console-window?forum=csharpgeneral) and a couple of fixes from me (tested on Windows 10):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int handle);

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr hConsole = GetStdHandle(-11);
            SetConsoleDisplayMode(hConsole, 1, out COORD b1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleDisplayMode(IntPtr ConsoleOutput, uint Flags, out COORD NewScreenBufferDimensions);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct COORD
        {
            public short X;
            public short Y;

            public COORD(short X, short Y)
            {
                this.X = X;
                this.Y = Y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```