# C# Cannot maximize Console from within the code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console

I tried Maximizing the Console .NET application using C# commands, but it doesn't work.

EDIT: I feel the need to specify that I use "Console App (.NET Framework)" and not "(Console App (NET Core))"
.NET Version is: 4.7.2
Windows version is: Windows 11 (With the new Terminal as my CMD)

This is what I tried:
Example1:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
private const int MAXIMIZE = 3;
private const int MINIMIZE = 6;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), MAXIMIZE);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

With this first example, if you type "MINIMIZE" instead of "MAXIMIZE", It does minimize, but it doesn't MAXIMIZE...

Example2:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(System.IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);

private static void Maximize()
{
    Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 3); //SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Maximize();
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximizing console window - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053112/maximizing-console-window-c-sharp)

Comment: micorsoft recommends https://stackoverflow.com/a/72326974/5193536

Comment: @Mikael I tried all 3 of them, in fact 2 of the examples I listed are literally from that page. But it is from 2014 so I thought things might have changed since then. A few months back I tried to do the same with a Forms application and it didin't work. Now I need it for a Console app.

Comment: @nbk As for the 2nd comment, for some reason it doesn't work either. I even tried starting the program from the build just in case, (And not debug)

Comment: Which .net version are you using and which windows version? I just tried your first example in .net core 6 and it maximized perfectly.

Comment: don net 7 doesn't work either it says that the max size is the windws size

Comment: even getting the correct screen size it will say it has the screen soze but the windo stas the same funny

Comment: I just realized I have been using Console App (.NET Framework) because it is mandatory for our school projects. Is there a way to do it in .NET 4.7.2/4.8?

Comment: Command Prompt, or Terminal, is not meant to be used in "visual" manner. Gone are the days of Norton Commander, and similar DOS apps. If your school project requires "visual" stuff, then do it in WinForms, or WPF (former is easier), with proper window instead of a console.

Comment: @Dialecticus I also use WinForms. But For this specific assignment I had to use Console. with .Net Framework specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code runs fine in Windows 10, but if you select Windows Terminal in Win11, your code will not work.

If you are using Win11:

Please open Settings=>Privacy&security=>For developers=>Terminal=>Change to Windows Console Host

If you don't find For developers in Privacy&security, you can also search For developers directly in the settings.

[image]

[image]

At this point, you can maximize the console program by using the code you provided again.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
private const int MAXIMIZE = 3;
private const int MINIMIZE = 6;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), MAXIMIZE);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Update:**

If you don't want to manually adjust the Windows Terminal to Windows Console Host, you can use the following code directly:

```
internal class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out Rect lpRect);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    private const int SW_RESTORE = 9; // Use SW_RESTORE to restore the window if it's minimized

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Import the necessary functions from user32.dll

        // Constants for the ShowWindow function
        const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
        // Get the handle of the console window
        IntPtr consoleWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();

        // Restore the window if it's minimized
        ShowWindow(consoleWindowHandle, SW_RESTORE);

        // Maximize the console window
        ShowWindow(consoleWindowHandle, SW_MAXIMIZE);

        // Get the screen size
        Rect screenRect;
        GetWindowRect(consoleWindowHandle, out screenRect);

        // Resize and reposition the console window to fill the screen
        var width = screenRect.Right - screenRect.Left;
        var height = screenRect.Bottom - screenRect.Top;
        MoveWindow(consoleWindowHandle, (int)screenRect.Left, (int)screenRect.Top, (int)width, (int)height, true);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

// Define the Rect structure
public struct Rect
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
```

Comment: I understand this solution, and I appreciate it, but since I am making a program, I cannot just expect everyone to do that before executing the app. I understand that it is Microsoft's laziness but isn't there a workaround for it? (Not just locally lol)

Comment: @Quidney Hi, I have updated the answer according to your request. If this is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people.